# Gradle custom task extends Exec is throwing error

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, devops, gradlew

My intention is to run a `docker save` command by creating a custom task in Gradle:

Below is my `build.gradle` file:

```
class SaveTask extends Exec {
    @TaskAction
    void saveImage() {
        commandLine "bash","-c","docker save someimage:latest | gzip > someimage.tar.gz"
    }
}

// Create a task using the task type
task save(type: SaveTask)
```

When I run the task it is giving me the below error:

```
Execution failed for task ':save'.
> execCommand == null!
```

Can someone suggest me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need to create a custom task type at all, just use the regular `Exec` task type for your task `save`:

```
task save(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "bash", "-c", "docker save someimage:latest | gzip > someimage.tar.gz"
}
```

The problem why your approach fails is that the `Exec` task type defines a `@TaskAction` internally. This `@TaskAction` runs the command defined by `commandLine`. In your `SaveTask` task type, another `@TaskAction` is defined, but it will run **after** the original `@TaskAction`. This is the reason why the `commandLine` is still null / empty for the original `@TaskAction`.

If you still want to create a custom task type, e.g. because you want to define a configuration interface that will be used by multiple tasks, use a `doFirst` closure to define the `commandLine`, as it will be executed **before** any task action:

```
class SaveTask extends Exec {
    String image

    SaveTask() {
        doFirst {
            commandLine "bash", "-c", "docker save ${image} | gzip > someimage.tar.gz"
        }
    }
}

task saveImageA(type: SaveTask) {
    image = 'imageA:latest'
}

task saveImageB(type: SaveTask) {
    image = 'imageB:latest'
}
```

Comment: no luck :( !! Getting the same error  execCommand == null

Comment: Did you use the first or the second snippet?

Comment: Second one . I  want to implement worker api on top of this.That is the reason of chosing a custom Gradle task

Answer (score 0):

I modified the above code as below and it's working for me

```
class SaveTask extends Exec {
     

    SaveTask() {

            commandLine "bash", "-c", "someimage:latest | gzip > someimage.tar.gz"

    }
}

task saveImageA(type: SaveTask)
```